# How to pick a random point from one of the sides of a pentagon?

Tags: python, geometry, 2d

In my program, I have 5 coordinates. In Python, I want to connect the 5 points together to form a pentagon, and know which points were connected to form each side. My goal is to then pick a random point from one of the sides of the pentagon. Does anyone know how I could write this in Python? I tried reading about convex hull but wasn't able to achieve anything, and I'm not sure if that is necessary for this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Can you use matplotlib.pyplot? If so use 'polygon' on the coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I used matplotlib.pyplot, in my code, would I be able to then find a point on one of the sides of the pentagon?

Comment: I would include your code here so the question is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to generate a point on a line segment:

```
x0 = x1 + a * (x2 - x1)
y0 = y1 + a * (y2 - y1)
```

, where `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` are start and end points of the segment and `a` is a number between 0 and 1.

Now, to solve your problem, you need two random numbers. First an integer to select a random side of the pentagon, and then a float between 0 and 1 to generate a random point on that side:

```
import random as rnd

i = rnd.randrange(5)
j = (i+1) % 5
t = rnd.uniform(0, 1)

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]

x0 = x[i] + t * (x[j] - x[i])
y0 = y[i] + t * (y[j] - y[i])
print(i, j, t, x0, y0)
```